# dir wildcard command in batch script displaying undesired results?

Tags: batch-file

Trying to run a batch script and using the command

dir *.pk3

results in the undesired effect of several things

```
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is xxxx-xxxx

 Directory of C:\bla\bla\

11/12/2013  02:27 PM           245,157 example.pk3
01/01/2015  03:05 AM           666,099 example2.pk3
06/12/2014  02:04 AM            16,980 example3.pk3
01/02/2015  01:33 PM       172,056,687 example4.pk3
               4 File(s)    172,984,923 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  1,759,760,351,232 bytes free
```

How do I get to to only say something like the following?

```
example.pk3
example2.pk3
example3.pk3
example4.pk3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `/B` (bare format) switch.

```
dir *.pk3 /B
```

This will strip all the headers and drive information and give you *only* the file names in the current directory.

---

As an extra tip, if you also append the `/S` switch it will give you full path of each file.

```
dir *.pk3 /B /S
```

Outputs:

```
C:\blah\blah\example.pk3
C:\blah\blah\example2.pk3
C:\blah\blah\example3.pk3
C:\blah\blah\example4.pk3
```

**However** this would also recurse into subdirectories as well so be careful if this is not desirable.